# Getting Compile time error on this code, help me out

Tags: java, arrays, ctl

I am getting compile time error for this code.
 Not getting what it is about, please help.
This is some practice question on codechef.

Tried to find on web but unable to find similar answers.

The code is-

```
import java.util.*;

class missp 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int t=sc.nextInt();
int i,j,n,c=0;
int a[];

while(t>0)
{
c=0;
n =sc.nextInt();
a[]=new int[n];

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
a[i]=sc.nextInt();

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{  
for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
{
if(a[i]==a[j])
{
c++;
break;
}
}
if(c=0)
System.out.println(a[i]);
break;
}
t--;
}
} 
}//end of class
```

the errors are-

```
  Main.java:16: error: not a statement
 a[]=new int[n];
  ^
 Main.java:16: error: ';' expected
 a[]=new int[n];
    ^
 Main.java:16: error: ']' expected
 a[]=new int[n];
             ^
 Main.java:16: error: ';' expected
 a[]=new int[n];
              ^
4 errors
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the brackets from `a[]=new int[n];`

You don't need to include the brackets when initializing because the variable name is "a", not "a[]".